# Jasmine Angular PrimeNG 16 test fails on WindowMaximizeIcon

Tags: angular, jasmine, primeng

I'm upgrading my Angular app from 15 to 16, and my Jasmine test involving PrimeNG's **dialog** fails as follows:

```
Chrome 114.0.0.0 (Windows 10) IncidentGridComponent should launch window when addItemClicked is called ... FAILED
    Error: NG0304: 'WindowMaximizeIcon' is not a known element (used in the 'Dialog' component template):
    1. If 'WindowMaximizeIcon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is a part of an @NgModule where this component is declared.
    2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
    error properties: Object({ code: 304 })
        at validateElementIsKnown (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:6000:23)
        at ɵɵelementStart (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:15286:9)
        at Module.ɵɵelement (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:15361:5)
        at templateFn (node_modules/primeng/fesm2022/primeng-dialog.mjs:866:84)
        at executeTemplate (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:10959:17)
        at renderView (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:12158:13)
        at TemplateRef.createEmbeddedViewImpl (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:22990:9)
        at ViewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:23255:37)
        at NgIf._updateView (node_modules/@angular/common/fesm2022/common.mjs:3316:45)
        at NgIf.set ngIf [as ngIf] (node_modules/@angular/common/fesm2022/common.mjs:3289:14)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had previously got **Dialog** component to work by incorrectly declaring Dialog, Header and Footer. The solution is to change the test as follows:

```
import { DialogModule } from 'primeng/dialog';
...
describe( ...
  beforeEach( ...
    TestBed.configureTestingModule( {
      imports: [
        ...
        DialogModule
      ],
      ...
  } ) );
```